# How to display text in different colors

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I am trying to create GUI using windows from application in c#. I have started recently. I have one problem in displaying some text information.

I am getting multiple sensors data, each sensor having the name and number and data. here i am able to get all sensors data into "_sensordata".

I able to print what ever the data coming from sensors in block color, for that purpose the below code is working perfectly. The problem is i want to put some conditions for each sensor data to display text in different color.

For example i have one sensor with name "Temperature". presently the temperature data and name of temperature sensor is displaying in block color. Now when the temperature is less than "0" or greater than "150" i want to display the value in "red color". I am not getting how to display like that. I have same type of conditions for each sensor,So how can implement this. I want to display the "sensorData.EngText" in "block" color if it is in between the range else i need to display in "red" color (for all sensors).

I have the below rich text format code so can any one suggest me how to add color to one of the text in the below code.

```
if (Display != null)
                    {        //UpdateDisplay1();
                        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                        text.Append("{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang1044");
                        text.Append("{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil Tahoma;}}");
                        text.Append("{\\colortbl;\\red0\\green0\\blue0;\\red255\\green0\\blue0;\\red255\\green255\\blue0;}");

                        text.Append("\\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard");
                        text.Append("{\\tx100\\tx2100\\tx4100\\tx6100\\tx8100\\tx10100");
                        text.Append("\\tx12100\\tx14100\\tx16100\\tx18100\\tx20100}");
                        text.Append("\\fs20\\ql\\b");
                        text.Append(string.Format("\\tab {0}", e.Data.SensorName));
                        text.Append("\\par\\fs35\\ql\\b0");
                        text.Append(string.Format("\\tab {0}", e.Data.EngText));

                        if (Display.InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            Display.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { Display.Rtf = text.ToString(); });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Display.Rtf = text.ToString();
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: I suggest saving a document from WordPad which has different colours in it, and checking the format in the generated file. I can't see a `colortbl` entry anywhere in your code...

Comment: @MatthewWatson I am new to c# programming and i don't know really that much about how to use rich text format in c sharp. Can you suggest me how to use "colortbl"in the above code or any examples.

Comment: It's a bit fiddly to say the least. I'm going to suggest that you use a library to produce the RTF (I'll add a link in an answer in a minute) - Or just use the built-in support of RichTextBox as mentioned by Jonathan.

Comment: Ok, so if the built-in RichTextBox functionality isn't sufficient (it should be!) check out http://sourceforge.net/projects/netrtfwriter/

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to manually construct RTFs - leave the work to RichTextBox!

```
richTextBox.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
richTextBox.AppendText("Text on red background");
richTextBox.SelectionBackColor = richTextBox.BackColor;
richTextBox.AppendText("Back to regular background");
```

Now, there are many RichText features that richTextBox doesn't support, for example line spacing - I P/Invoked SendMessage messages for that.

Comment: Is it OK if i add these lines to my code or i need to replace my code with your code. Please let me know do i need to use any namespace system for that purpose.

Comment: RichTextBox has many "SelectionXXX" properties, including `SelectionColor`. I don't know what "Display" in your code actually is, but if you can can the actual RichTextBox control, you can use its properties.